# Stop script load error popup in IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-webpages

i am getting some problem on script load in IE 8.

Error popup show message something like that

Error:**A script on this page is causing internet Explorer to run slowly.if it continues to run ,your computer may become unresponsive.do you want to abort the script**

i have googleing too much and also getting some solution but that all not stopping  this popup,
i have also tried to increase script timeout but still showing the popup,even also try from registry to increase script load time but its not working .please guys help me to solve this issue.this error popup showing in IE8 and below this version.i have to make it runnable in IE 8 as per client requirements ,so please help me.

thanks

Answer (score 3):

This is a known problem with IE 8. It basically means that the browser is complaining that an operation is taking a long time to complete, and it's offering the user the opportunity to exit the operation since the UI is non responsive when the script is running.

One common fix is to break your script into smaller chunks and call each chunk in a setTimeout. You have to be carful to ensure that you can maintain the original order of execution though.

```
setTimeout(function(){
  //break your function into smaller pieces that can be called separately. 
},5);
```

This gives the browser the opportunity to breath in between chunks, so it won't see it as one long running script any more.

One common use case of this is if you have independent iterations in a loop that can be executed independent of each other.

Another alternative is to optimize the JavaScript that you're executing. It's very common to have slow JQuery selectors that can be optimized using common best practices

Comment: i have use this SetTimeout function but still it showing,i have already mention in question about this function.

Comment: Ok, keep in mind that the second argument that you pass to setTimeOut is not the timeout for the code block, but the time until the method is slated to start - meaning the higher the value the longer you must wait for that code to run. If setTimeout doesn't work, then you have to optimize the code or change your client side approach. We need more details to help you

Answer (score 0):

There is no code based solution to your problem. You may be able to solve this on a client by client basis however i'm sure that's not what you want.

The best way to get rid of this message is improve your code. Why is the code taking so long to run? Is this not something you could run asynchronously on the server and then just return the response?

Answer (score 0):

Message is directing you to the point that some of the code of your jquery have a infinite or it is taking too much time, you have to change the logic of the loop and have to minimize the iterations, if sample code was available than can suggest.